# New Users Not Allowed to Add Tags - Which One is New?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I was posting a question on Stack Overflow

As I was tagging my question with keywords, the site told me new users are not able to create new tags, but it wouldn't tell me which one was new.  So I had to delete the tags to figure out which one was new.

I would be nice if this could be updated to state which is the problem tag.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and venture it is $_FILES and/or CGI.pm...

Comment: You can post a pic now!

Comment: Thanks I updated the post to include the screen shot.

Comment: I think your tags are a bit too specific when you start putting function/variable names inside them...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's auto-complete on the tags so the new one should be the one that didn't have a drop-down with suggestions in it. This doesn't help you after the fact, but should help when entering them in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say clarifying the message to indicate which are new is not an unreasonable suggestion.  The code obviously knows which one(s) it didn't find.  Perhaps adding some text on how to select tags if your rep is under 250 to the question page would be helpful