# List which tag is 'new'

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Users Not Allowed to Add Tags - Which One is New?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/new-users-not-allowed-to-add-tags-which-one-is-new)

I just went to ask a question and was given this error message:

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

> new users can't create tags
>   'education etiquette questions discussion' contains a new tag

Fair enough to restrict new users from creating a new tag, but how am I to know which one is new?  I was able to use the auto-complete to figure out which one was new, but not everyone may be able to figure this out.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate. *searching*

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/new-users-not-allowed-to-add-tags-which-one-is-new